# Visual Studio 2017 Is Now Pausing Randomly

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2017

I bravely started to use VS2017 Community Edition near to when it was first released, however in the last few weeks or so I have noticed large changes in performance issues:

- When selecting text and typing the new text I want, I see no changes. The editor doesn't lock up, but nothing changes though I have already typed the new text that I want in its place. After about 5 seconds, the text is suddenly typed really quickly by the editor as if it's playing catchup.
- When pasting text, I see a box telling me its now "formatting pasted text". This is new. This even appears for one / two line pastes. Again, it pauses the editor for about 4-5 seconds as above.
- Refactoring a class name that's used in one text file in a single-file project no more than two different places I will see a box like the "formatting paste" box above that informs me it's renaming the class. Again, pause for about 4-5s.

I'm not using resharper (that really didn't play nice with vs2017) and even without any extensions, the same behaviour occurs. I have no applications in the background running that drain the system.

Has anyone noticed this recently, or could it be something else?

Comment: I'm getting the "formatting pasted text" delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution - the Git plugin. I noticed "Git for windows" kept appearing in the task manager when idle eating up RAM and CPU but thought nothing of it. Disabling the Git plugin in Tools/Options/(type source in the search bar)/Source plugin to "none" appears to have fixed the performance issues.

Git has been buggy / unusable in VS for years.